# C: I can't display the content of an array [CodeBlocks]

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I have this code to copy array **temp** to array **a**
and I don't know why it keep displaying the Addresses of the values... and not the values

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#define maxLength 14
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef short int *set;

void copyarr(set a,set temp){
    int i;
a=(int*)malloc(maxLength*sizeof(short int));
for(i=0;i<maxLength;i++)
    a[i]=temp[i];

}

int main(){
    int i;
set a,temp;
    temp=(int*)malloc(maxLength*sizeof(short int));
     for(i=0;i<maxLength;i++)
        temp[i]=i+10;

     copyarr(a,temp);

     for(i=0;i<maxLength;i++)
        printf("%d ",a[i]);
}
```

**EDIT**

Updated code: and still get the same results , I did what was shown in the FAQ link

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#define maxLength 14
#define maxSetLength 129
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef short int *set;

int *copyarr(set a,set temp){
    int i;
a=(int*)malloc(maxLength*sizeof(short int));
for(i=0;i<maxLength;i++)
    a[i]=temp[i];
return &a;
}

int main(){
    int i;
set a,temp;
    temp=(int*)malloc(maxLength*sizeof(short int));
     for(i=0;i<maxLength;i++)
        temp[i]=i+10;

     copyarr(&a,temp);

     for(i=0;i<maxLength;i++)
        printf("%d ",a[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define maxLength 14

typedef short int *set;

void copyarr(set *a, set temp){
    int i;
    *a=malloc(maxLength*sizeof(short int));
    for(i=0;i<maxLength;i++)
        (*a)[i]=temp[i];
}

int main(){
    int i;
    set a,temp;
    temp = malloc(maxLength*sizeof(short int));
    for(i=0;i<maxLength;i++)
        temp[i]=i+10;

    copyarr(&a,temp);

    for(i=0;i<maxLength;i++)
        printf("%d ",a[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> a=(int*)malloc(maxLength*sizeof(short int));
> ```

That has no effect whatsoever for the caller. In your code `a` is a pointer and all you are doing is changing **your local copy** of the pointer. At the end of the day, in `main` `a` still points to nothing. This problem is well discussed in this [C FAQ](http://c-faq.com/ptrs/passptrinit.html).

---

This confusion is partly caused by hiding the fact that `a` is a pointer behind the `typedef`. You use it like a pointer and depend on the fact that it's a pointer but you hide this information. You should only use typedefs when the caller genuinely shouldn't care what the actual type is.

Comment: but this is not the real code , am working on a big project and dont need to type everytime `short int set[]` , so i wanna use **SET** only , so how i can do that with still using typedef

Comment: but it when i do printf in the function it displays ! why in main() it wont ! , i returned the pointer !

Comment: @user3225284 Because `main` doesn't see the change.

Comment: then how i can make main see this change ? i read the FAQ and did like what was showe

Answer (score 0):

```
typedef short int *set;

set copyarr(set temp){
    int i;
    set b;
    b=(set)malloc(maxLength*sizeof(short int));
    for(i=0;i<maxLength;i++)
        b[i]=temp[i];
    return b;
}

int main(){
    int i;
    set a,temp;
    temp=(set)malloc(maxLength*sizeof(short int));
    for(i=0;i<maxLength;i++)
       temp[i]=i+10;

    a = copyarr(temp);

    for(i=0;i<maxLength;i++)
       printf("%d ",a[i]);
    free(a);
    free(temp);
    return 0;
}
```

Edit:

```
typedef short int *set;

void copyarr(set a, set temp){
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<maxLength;i++)
        a[i]=temp[i];
    return;
}

int main(){
    int i;
    set a,temp;
    temp=(set)malloc(maxLength*sizeof(short int));
    a=(set)malloc(maxLength*sizeof(short int));
    for(i=0;i<maxLength;i++)
       temp[i]=i+10;

    copyarr(a, temp);

    for(i=0;i<maxLength;i++)
       printf("%d ",a[i]);
    free(a);
    free(temp);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: how i can do it without assigning **B** , i want to display in main using **A**

Comment: There is no `b` in main. Only `a`.

Comment: I understand but is there anyway to do it with doing a=copyarr(temp)?

Comment: Do you mean **without** doing a=copyarr(temp)?